# Mythubuntu: Integrate mythubuntu in xbmc and time programming

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have 2 questions about Mythubuntu:

1. How can i integrade Mythubuntu (for watching live tv & record it)  in xbmc? Do i have to install mythubuntu first, and then install xbmc? Or is there a plugin in xbmc for mythubuntu?
2. If you want to record a tv-program, wil the computer automaticly wake up if it must record something?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mythbuntu, it is a complete OS, so that needs to be installed before XBMC.

Instructions of how to configure XBMC to interact with MythTV: http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=MythTV

MythTV does support ACPI wakeup : http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup

> MythTV has the ability to write the date and time of the next
>   recording to the RTC. This allows your machine to automatically
>   shutdown (or suspend) and turn on again a few minutes before it needs
>   to record again.